# can i execute a launch file or run a node through RosWebTool

Tags: ros, rosbridge, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am now using roswebtool(roslibjs) to communicate with rosbridge

so i can publish topic and subscribe topic in website

now i want to remote execute a launch file or run a node in website, is that possible?

or is there any other method to run the node when i want to ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268044/can-i-execute-a-launch-file-or-run-a-node-through-roswebtool/) by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When you use roslibjs with rosbridge, your website is not a node, but it can be seen as a node (it just don't register with the rosmaster, so you can't see him with "rosnode list"). Rosbridge act as a proxy to use ROS functionnalities.

The easiest way to launch a remote process from your website is to use a process management library like [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system), [boost::process](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.starting_a_process) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) ,  there are all available in ROS ([POCO need this)](http://answers.ros.org/question/189788/how-can-use-external-library-in-ros/)

For an example with std::system (will quit the callback only when the process finish):

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>

    void callback(std_msgs::String msg){
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "roslaunch " << msg.data;
        std::system(ss.str().c_str());//std::system only accept c_str() a.k.a char*
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
        ros::init(argc,argv,"roslaunch_launcher");
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/launch", 1, callback);
        ros::spin();
        return 0;
    }
```

Just publish a string in the form "< package name > < launch file name >" and the launch file should be called

You also should be sure to source the correct environment BEFORE launch this node, if you try to launch a file from an another workspace (not sourced) or you create a package after launching this node, the loaded environmnent will not find the launch file.

And an example with POCO (with a run/kill procedure):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include "Poco/Process.h"
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>


Poco::ProcessHandle* ph;
bool running = false;

void callback_run(std_msgs::String msg){
    if(!running){
        std::vector<std::string> args;
        boost::split(args, msg.data, boost::is_any_of(" ") ); //Split the msg.data on space and save it to a vector
        Poco::ProcessHandle ph_running = Poco::Process::launch("roslaunch", args,0,0,0); //launch a new node
        ph = new Poco::ProcessHandle(ph_running); // Copy the processhandler to our global variable
        running = true; //Refuse new launch
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("launched : roslaunch" << msg.data);
    }
    else{
        ROS_ERROR("A process is already running.");
    }
}

void callback_kill(std_msgs::Empty msg){
    if(running){
        Poco::Process::requestTermination(ph->id()); //send SIGINT
            Poco::Process::wait(*ph); //Wait for roslaunch to kill every node
        free(ph);  
        running = false;  //accept a new launch
        ROS_INFO("Killed process");
    }
    else{
        ROS_ERROR("No Process are running.");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "node_runner");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub_run = n.subscribe("/run",100,callback_run);
    ros::Subscriber sub_kill = n.subscribe("/kill",100,callback_kill);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

This example subscribe 2 topics : /run and /kill. Run will accept a node package a name (example : 'rqt_gui rqt_gui') and kill accept a std_msgs/Empty.

This need a little work, as the std::system example will block the subscriber (the function return only when the process die).

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) on 2017-08-06**:
thank you so so much, that works!!!
there is anthoer question:  how to stop this launch remote?

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-08-07**:
I added an example with POCO to run and kill a process, it work with rosrun but not with roslaunch... I think roslaunch spawn multiple process and detach them, but I don't know how to kill them. If you find a solution I will be happy to see it :)

**Comment by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) on 2017-08-08**:
i use std::system start launch files and nodes.  and kill the nodes the same way using "rosnode kill node" command. if i start a launch, i have to know or record which nodes are started, and kill them using **nodekill**,"rosnode kill node1 node2 node3"

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-08-08**:
Nice, that work too.
I found a way to do it with Poco, with the use of Poco::Process::requestTermination() instead of kill(), it send a SIGINT to the roslaunch and close all nodes launched.

**Comment by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) on 2017-08-08**:
great, so thanks

**Comment by [molnardk](https://answers.ros.org/users/32640/molnardk/) on 2017-11-15**:
Hello i just found this article. I would like to do the same as you, from a webpage. Do you mind sharing your final solution of this code for me?
Did you manage to start/stop all kind of nodes?
Thank you for your answer :)

**Comment by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) on 2017-11-15**:
Hi, yes I made some buttons to start/stop all kind of nodes, I write a service in robot to process the request of start/stop nodes, and use std:system to start node and use nodekill to stop node. you can also use @Imathieu 's method

**Comment by [molnardk](https://answers.ros.org/users/32640/molnardk/) on 2017-11-16**:
I will give a look, thank you :)

**Comment by [molnardk](https://answers.ros.org/users/32640/molnardk/) on 2017-11-23**:
I just started using ROS and managed to build the example with std::system.
How i can publish a sting to it? I tried : rostopic pub /launch std_msgs/String rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket
Also: can i start more than 1 node?(i mean i dont stop them) and what about the 2nd method the POCO?

**Comment by [molnardk](https://answers.ros.org/users/32640/molnardk/) on 2017-11-23**:
[rosbridge_server] is neither a launch file in package [roslaunch] nor is [roslaunch] a launch file name
it gives me this error also

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-11-23**:
have you tried : `rostopic pub /launch std_msgs/String "data: 'rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch'"` ?

The first method can only launch 1 process (rosrun or roslaunch), as std::system(..) is a blocking function. You can find alternative in python (like Popen) or in cpp (fork, boost,etc.)

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-11-23**:
Also, if you want more than 1 process to spawn with the 2nd method, you need to save all Poco::ProcessHandler in a vector to  delete them at the end of your node (remove the `bool running` and create a vector of ProcessHandler and delete them all at the end).

**Comment by [molnardk](https://answers.ros.org/users/32640/molnardk/) on 2017-11-23**:
rostopic pub /launch std_msgs/String "data: 'rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch'" this is works :) thank you i misunderstood the format :)
Yeah i wanted to remote start multiple nodes (like i type the node at the webpage and it starts it, and start an other) Thank you for you answer :)

**Comment by [james P M](https://answers.ros.org/users/56428/james-p-m/) on 2021-09-13**:
i want to launch some node from webtools. can you guys share some template for writing cmake and xml file for this and how to add boost and poco library.

**Comment by [meropis](https://answers.ros.org/users/121372/meropis/) on 2022-10-21**:
For roslibjs I have to include a messageType. Would that just be std_msgs/String? Also, in my publish code I have two objects argc and argv - is this correct too? Do I pass argc the name of my package and argv the name of the launch file?

```
var survey = new ROSLIB.Message({
    argc : "<package name>",
    argv : "<launch file name>"
});
cmdVel.publish(survey);
```

Does this look right? I'm not quite sure I follow